# How can I update tuples with no primary key in SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have a table `updatetab` with columns and sample data like this:

```
Ab_id  cf_id  numbrr
--------------------
234     34.    12345
234.    34.    89157
234.    34.    59736
456.    54.    67385
456.    54.    73568
456.    54.    09879
```

The `numbrr` is the contact detail of a person .. I will update/insert a record in the table.. The problem is how can I delete the old record and update/insert the new one? The records are from an Excel file

Comment: Have a look at MERGE statement of sql. That will help you to achieve your task.

Comment: You are going to insert how many records ?

Comment: do you have any duplicated rows? (and by that I mean rows that *all* of the values are the same as other rows)

Comment: Hundreds of records.

Comment: There will be no duplicated rows

Answer (score 1):

The MERGE statement will solve the problem. Here is the basic version for MERGE.

```
MERGE INTO table as tgt using (SELECT * FROM table) AS src ON src.Id = tgt.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    //Your update query
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    //Your insert query
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

Comment: Thank you! What is tgt.id column?

Comment: That's alias to the first table and id should be the Ab_id in your case.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this!:)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to copy formula in excel like:

```
="UPDATE updatetab SET ... WHERE numbrr = '"&A2&"' IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN INSERT updatetab(...) VALUES '"&C2&"' ...END"
```

And copy down this formula then copy - paste results into Managment Studio and run It.

This formula is like SQL query:

```
UPDATE updatetab SET ... WHERE etc = etc2
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT updatetab(...) VALUES (...) ...;
END
```

Comment: I cant. The user will upload the file and not me.

Comment: @hellopanda Huh... But you can edit excel file... Whatever you can use SQL query which I provided...